# use Google spreadsheet connector wso2

Tags: google-sheets, wso2, wso2-esb

I would like to use the google spreadsheet connector at https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/tree/048e223c037b447c3f77c2b7e72338dc26ea5c46/googlespreadsheet. But it is not found in [wso2 store](https://store.wso2.com/store/). I would like to know how I can compile it and use the connector from github. Please help

Comment: what is the ESB version that you use?

Comment: the version is 4.9.0

Answer (score 1):

Generally git wont allow you to get a folder. so you need to go with `svn` approach. follow bellow instruction as it is. (assumtion on you are woking in linux / mac enviorment. if not make the command the way works on windows.

1. create new directory where ever you want and navigate inside that

   `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wso2/esb-connectors/048e223c037b447c3f77c2b7e72338dc26ea5c46/pom.xml`
2. `mkdir wso2`
3. `cd wso2`
4. `mkdir esbconnector`
5. `cd esbconnector/`
6. `mkdir googlespreadhseet`
7. `cd googlespreadhseet/`
8. `svn checkout https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/trunk/googlespreadsheet/googlespreadsheet-connector/googlespreadsheet-connector-2.0.0/org.wso2.carbon.connector`
9. `cd org.wso2.carbon.connector/`

   `mvn clean install`

it may take little time as its required to download few artifacts. if its ended up with error that integration test not found get the integration test Base from the same repo and build that first. then rebuild the connector

Answer (score 1):

Recently Google spreadsheet Version2 connector has been created with REST API and added to WSO2 store. The Connector zip file can be downloaded from [here](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/0fc5c719-334e-494a-acb8-bf0a00f496cc). Go to the link and click the 'download connector' button and follow the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Google+Spreadsheet+REST+Operations) for the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the connector source from the https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/blob/master/googlespreadsheet and built it.
Then add the connector to the ESB from the UI according to the https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Managing+Connectors+in+Your+ESB+Instance